# Execution error Encountered the symbol "IF" when expecting one of the following

Tags: oracle, plsql, logical-operators, declare

Error occurred during SQL query execution

```
Reason:
SQL Error [6550] [65000]: ORA-06550: line 11, column 1:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "IF" when expecting one of the following:

   := . ( % ;
The symbol ";" was substituted for "IF" to continue.
ORA-06550: line 31, column 15:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "(" when expecting one of the following:

   , from
```

------------------------Code starts here--------

```
DECLARE
    TOTALCOUNT int ;
BEGIN
    SELECT
    count(*) AS cnt
INTO
    TOTALCOUNT
FROM
    abc;

dbms_output.put_line (TOTALCOUNT) ;
END ;

DECLARE
    TOTALPTCOUNT int ;
BEGIN
    SELECT
    count(*) AS cnt
INTO
    TOTALPTCOUNT
FROM
    ghi g;

dbms_output.put_line (TOTALPTCOUNT) ;
END ;

DECLARE
    TOTALOVERALLCOUNT int ;
BEGIN   
    SELECT 
    ((TOTALPTCOUNT/TOTALCOUNT) * 100) AS dpc
INTO
    TOTALOVERALLCOUNT FROM dual ;
dbms_output.put_line (TOTALOVERALLCOUNT) 

IF:
    TOTALOVERALLCOUNT >= 10 THEN

"my logic here"

end 
if ;
```

Comment: You have not specified which DBMS you are using. Looking into your code should there be ";" after dbms_output.put_line (TOTALOVERALLCOUNT) ??

Comment: Its not SQL Server when you are getting Oracle errors. Please only tag a single RDBMS.

Answer (score 1):

The first two PL/SQL blocks are OK (as far as syntax is concerned). Though, consider terminating them with a slash.

However, the 3rd block is completely malformed:

- `IF` can't have a string enclosed into double quotes (you should probably put the "my logic here" into a comment and use `NULL;` command, just to make it compile
- variable shouldn't have a colon (you aren't using any binds here)
- to compute its value, you don't have to `SELECT FROM DUAL` - just *calculate* it
- also, `END` is missing.

Moreover, as the 3rd block uses variables declared in the first two, it just won't work - they are unknown here. You should probably have only one `DECLARE` section, declare all 3 variables, put all "logic" into a single PL/SQL block. Something like this:

```
DECLARE
   totalcount         INT;
   totalptcount       INT;
   totaloverallcount  INT;
BEGIN
   SELECT COUNT (*) INTO totalcount FROM abc;

   DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (totalcount);

   SELECT COUNT (*)
     INTO totalptcount
     FROM ghi g;

   DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (totalptcount);

   totaloverallcount := (totalptcount / totalcount) * 100;

   DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (totaloverallcount);

   IF totaloverallcount >= 10                  --> your IF is completely wrong
   THEN
      NULL;
   -- "my logic here"
   END IF;
END;
/
```

Comment: Thank you for this @Littlefoot. I ended up declaring all variables together inside one block and I got it to work however my problem is still that I want IF condition to be satisfied whenever applicable and then execute 'my logic' part and output however I am unable to get it to work .I have also tried using case statements instead of IF but it wouldnt work. Any suggestions there ?

This is how my modified code looks like

Comment: Thank you for this @Littlefoot. I ended up declaring all variables together inside one block and I got it to work however my problem is still the IF statement wouldnt work and throws the error .I have also tried using case statements instead of IF but it wouldn't work. Any suggestions there ? When I run declare block and my logic block separately they run without any errors so I guess I am not joining them correctly using IF so if you can correct me what I am doing wrong or how to properly apply IF in my logic would be appreciated. TIA

Comment: This is how my modified code looks like
DECLARE
 TOTALCOUNT int ; TOTALPTCOUNT int ; TOTALOVERALLCOUNT int ;
BEGIN
 SELECT
    count(*) AS cnt
INTO
    TOTALCOUNT
FROM
    abc;
dbms_output.put_line (TOTALCOUNT) ;
SELECT
    count(*) AS cnt
INTO
    TOTALPTCOUNT
FROM
    ghi g;
dbms_output.put_line (TOTALPTCOUNT) ;
TOTALOVERALLCOUNT:= ((TOTALPTCOUNT / TOTALCOUNT) * 100) ;
dbms_output.put_line (TOTALOVERALLCOUNT) ;
IF TOTALOVERALLCOUNT > 1 THEN
"My logic here"
END IF ;
END ;

Comment: The only obviously wrong thing is a double-quoted string `"My logic here"`. You should put some code in there, i.e. "your logic". I don't know what that logic is - that's why I put a `null;` command there.